# Navigating through different pages

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface, dart

I am developing a kind of a travel app showing nice buildings in a particular city. My home screen consists of two "scroll horizontally" containers, showing the buildings by title. Let's say b1 is first and b2 second on the list. What I want to do is when I am tapping b1, to get the details page of b1, and when I tap on b2 to be redirected in the details page of b2. Currently I have just passed the info of b1, so whenever tapping on any building, I get the b1 details page. How can I pass the data on the onTap function so that whenever I select a building to get the respective details page for each one?

Comment: See this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation

Answer (score 0):

use the Navigator to push or replace the current page:

```dart
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute(buildinginfo)),
  );
}
```

To go back just call `Navigator.pop()` from within the SecondRoute page.

You can provide arguments to the SecondRoute widget from wich you can display certain information. For example the building information.

Answer (score 0):

got it, do I also need to set when a certain building is tapped on the firstScreen in order to get its respective details with the Navigate.push()? If so, is it passed as argument too?